# regex only match the first content

Tags: php, regex

I have the following html code.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {"foo" : "bar"}
</script>

<script type="application/ld+json">
    {"foo" : "bar"}
</script>

<script type="application/ld+json">
    {"foo" : "bar"}
</script>
```

I am trying to grab the json content from inside the first script. But if I do

```
/<script type="application\/ld\+json">{.*}<\/script>/
```

it gives everything before the first script opening tag and the last script closing tag. if I do

```
/<script type="application\/ld\+json">{.*?}<\/script>/
```

for some reason, I only get the second part.

Is there anyway to get the {} json part from the first tag?

Comment: It sounds to me like you are using a function wrong. Please state the language and show the code. The first regex looks fine.

Comment: @Denziloe I am using PHP

Comment: @Denziloe to be more concise, `preg_match('/<script type="application\/ld\+json">{.*?}<\/script>/', $html, $matches);`

Answer (score 3):

that should not even compile.. but anyway looks like you confused greedy and nongreedy and the type of brackets, {X} means that the group before can be there x amount of time, and not whatever is in x any amount of time that's []*

what you need is something like this

```
/<script type="application\/ld\+json">[^\{]*?{(.*?)\}[^\}]*?<\/script>/s
```

Use the object index 1 in the match object returned from the preg_match and you will have your JSON.

repl.it for a running PHP example(code below): https://repl.it/GNdD/0

link to try the regex out: https://regex101.com/r/AouzRm/10

```php
$in = '<script type="application/ld+json">';
$in .= '{"foo" : "bar"}';
$in .= '</script>';

$in .= '<script type="application/ld+json">';
$in .= '    {"foo" : { "bar" : "boo" } }';
$in .= '</script>';

$in .= '<script type="application/ld+json">';
$in .= '    {"foo" : { "bar" : { "boo" : "goo" }}}';
$in .= '</script>';

$matches = [];
$allMatches = [];

preg_match('/<script type="application\/ld\+json">[^\{]*?{(.*?)\}[^\}]*?<\/script>/s',$in,$matches);
preg_match_all('/<script type="application\/ld\+json">[^\{]*?{(.*?)\}[^\}]*?<\/script>/s',$in,$allMatches);

echo "from the preg_match:\n";
print_r("$matches[1]\n\n");

echo "from the preg_match_all:\n";
print_r($allMatches[1]);
```

Comment: The curly braces are presumably there to match the JSON container.

Comment: {.*} is not even a valid thing... http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php

Comment: o way i think i get it, wait not nvm

Comment: you should keep the curly braces out of the regex as you could have something like this: { foo : { bar : "boo" } }

Comment: i'll edit the thing to include the braces and not break

Comment: @Denziloe better?

Comment: @guillaumemercier Have you see the regex demo you linked to? I get the same result as shown in the page, which I think it wrong. I get something like `<script type="application/ld+json">
    {`

Comment: @user7342807 I've updated the post to include a more relevant and more functional answer that will be capable of understanding more complex regex. As for your remark that's because you have to get the element from the regex match #1 or #2 for the old example, I've added a repl.it links if you are looking for a live example.

Answer (score 1):

As @Denziloe said, your regex looks alright.

It might be a problem with the fact you are not accounting for newlines and whitespace within the script tags.

Check this example and see if that fixes it, otherwise there is probably something wrong with your implementation. I also think you want to add a capture group like I did to have easier access to the JSON part itself

`<script type="application\/ld\+json">\s*({.*?})\s*<\/script>` [working example](https://regex101.com/r/fKxypl/2)

Comment: This doesn't return anything. I have actually removed all new lines, tabs from the html using str_replace. As I said in the question, the problem is not getting the content, but getting which one

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the "second json content"

Comment: the second {} part from my example

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following *regex* :

```
(?s)>.*?(?={)\K.*?}
```

*see* **[*regex demo / explanation*](https://regex101.com/r/EwUmym/3)**

**PHP** ( [demo](https://ideone.com/JmTWGy) )

```
$r = '/(?s)>.*?(?={)\K.*?}/';
$s = '<script type="application/ld+json">
    {"foo1" : "bar1"}
</script>

<script type="application/ld+json">
    {"foo2" : "bar2"}
</script>

<script type="application/ld+json">
    {"foo3" : "bar3"}
</script>';
preg_match($r, $s, $o);
print_r($o);
```

Answer (score 1):

From a PHP standpoint... Maybe you're not accessing `$matches` correctly?
Assuming you'd want `{"one" : "bar"}` from the following example

```
<?php

$html = '<script type="application/ld+json">
    {"one" : "bar"}
</script>

<script type="application/ld+json">
    {"two" : "bar"}
</script>

<script type="application/ld+json">
    {"three" : "bar"}
</script>';

$pattern = '/<script type="application\/ld\+json">\s*(\{.*?\})\s*<\/script>/s';

preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $matches);

$whatYouWant = $matches[1][0];

echo $whatYouWant;
```

[You can see the execution of this code here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2a5fd81c37133f7eb0e8f1155bb857cb8b4f19e6)